# Loop through two arrays without multiplying the result by 1st array length * 2nd array length

Tags: php, html, checkboxlist

I have two arrays responds back from server:

1. The list of all allergies that exist
2. The list of allergies in specific product

I need to display list of check-boxes of all allergies and mark the ones that exist in the other array as checked.

The second array can be `null`.

How can I loop through both arrays without multiplying the results by `array1 * array2`.

This code results into 8 check-box inputs because the list of all allergies is 4 and the product has only 2 allergies so the loop is executed 8 times!

```
<?php
$checked ="";
if (isset($allergies)) {  // array of all allergies
    foreach ($allergies as $key => $value) {
        if(isset ($productAllergies)) {  // array of product allergies
            foreach ($productAllergies as $productkey => $prodValue) {
                // echo 'product allergy'. $prodValue['allergy_id'] .' general'.$key ;
                if( $prodValue['allergy_id'] ==$key )
                    $checked ='checked';
                else
                    $checked ='';

?>
<?php
            } // foeach close
        } // if close ?>
            <input type="checkbox" name="allergy[]" value="<?php echo $key; ?>"  <?php echo $checked; ?>/> 
            <label>
                <?php echo $value; ?>
            </label>
<?php } // foreach close
} // if close
?>
```

Can somebody help to clarify the logic I should follow to display the checkbox list with checked values.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the format properly this could work:

```
<?php
  $checked ="";     
  if (isset($allergies)) {  // array of all allergies
      foreach ($allergies as $key => $value) {

          if(isset ($productAllergies)){  // array of product allergies
              $k2 = array_search($key, $productAllergies);
              if (!empty($productAllergies[$k2])) {
                 $checked = 'checked';
              }
           }
       }

   }
  ?>
```

Comment: how can I display the list of all allergies?? It should loop through it also

Comment: The second parameter of array_search should be 2 dimension array?? Does it work for array of objects??

Comment: I think it's better to make customized search function